# programmatically create environment variables using batch script

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, environment-variables

On application start, I want to store certain application configuration keys (ex: directory path, database connection string) as an environment variable by running a `batch script`. I have tried this by writing Powershell script as guided in this article [here](https://cmatskas.com/application-configuration-settings-across-multiple-environments/), which works absolutely fine. I tried the same using the `batch` file like below but it doesn't seem to be working.

Below is sample of `.bat` file which I am trying to load/configure at the application start.

EDIT: Correcting `.bat` the script as suggested by *Compo* in the comment section below.

```
@echo off
SET "LOG=api.log"
SET "DATABASE_URL=host=xyz.rs.aws.com dbname=somename user=someuser password=somepassword sslmode=enable"
SET "LISTEN_PROTOCOL=http"
@echo on
```

Below is sample code used to run the sample.bat file and fetch the value,

```
    string batFilePath = string.Format(@"D:\sample.bat");
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batFilePath ;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.Start()
    proc.WaitForExit();

   // fetch the value set by batch file
   var data = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOG"); // returns null here
```

However, I also wanted to know, Is it possible to create and store environment variables at the application process level? i.e. I should be able to use these environment variables only within the application level, not at the system/user level.

Comment: I would suggest that you fix your batch file, because currently you're not creating a `%LOG%` variable, you're creating a `%LOG<SPACE>%` variable with a value of `<SPACE>"api.log"`. It should read, `Set "LOG=api.log"`, `Set "DATABASE_URL=host=xyz.rs.aws.com dbname=somename user=someuser password=somepassword sslmode=enable"` and `Set "LISTEN_PROTOCOL=http"`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a bat file rather than C# or PowerShell?  You are already calling GetEnvironmentVariable from C# so why not have C# call  SetEnvironmentVariable? It also looks like this supports a target of the current process https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netcore-3.1#System_Environment_SetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_String_System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_

Comment: @AlanMacdonald well, it's as per the requirement actually... I don't have much knowledge of either `.bat` or `Powershell` programming but as mentioned just tried with Powershell to see if it works. Calling `SetEnvironmentVariable` implies we need to pass a variable value to the program in order to set the value right? and from where the values I can pass from, I am not supposed to use app config/web config or Jason files. That's the main reason I am trying to run `.bat` file on load.

Comment: @ash, instead of providing unspecific statements like didn't work, provide debugging information so that we can help you. I didn't provide an answer, I offered advice by way of comment. What I can tell you though, is that without following my advice, it was never going to work.

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, you seem to think that the variables, defined in your batch file will still exist once that batch file has completed. That is an incorrect assumption, because when it does close, the specifc cmd.exe instance it was using, throws away/undefines, all of  those variables. To still do it from a batch file, you could use the `setx` command instead. Open a Command Prompt window, type `setx /?`, press thge 'ENTER' key, and read its usage information.

Comment: hey @Compo, noted. What I meant was, I tried exactly the way you suggested to me i.e. by correcting the `.bat` file by _removing extra spaces and using quotes_. As you mentioned in your last comment agree my assumption was wrong. Now, I have changed all 3 `set` commands to `setx` in my `.bat` file and then tried executing it. However seems to be no difference, lemme try some workarounds.

Comment: Once again, I didn't provide an answer, my comment was to correct the command you were using to what seemd like a more appropriate one for the scenario you were describing. If you want help with your new methodology, then the most efficient way to get that is to **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61558760/edit)**, providing your new code and sufficient information for willing helpers to replicate your issue, and consequently assist you.

Comment: Does Powershell re-read the environment variables at all? Environment variables are copied into process memory on process creation. Unless the application does something itself, later, changing the system environment variables will not affect existing processes.

Comment: note that `setx` syntax differs from `set` syntax. So only adding the `x` isn't enough.